# Trying to import external common component in expo form outside the root directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, babel-loader

[image: this is the babel.config.js]

**This is the common component**

```
import React from "react";
// import { Text } from "react-native";
const PrintHello = () => {
  return <div> Hello Im working </div>;
};

export default PrintHello;
// import _ from "lodash";
```

**this is the folder structure**

```
common/components

app1/src/components

app2/src
```

**And i got this error**

```
/Users/mac3/Documents/GitHub/curb-food/common/utils.js 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // import { Text } from "react-native";
| const PrintHello = () => {
>   return <div> Hello Im working </div>;
| };
|
```

i tried all the babel-loader but nothing workes

Comment: Hey, any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The file type should be `.jsx` to handle React components instead of `.js`. Also `<div>` is not a React Native component, you should be using `<Text>`. If you change the file name to `utils.jsx` and replace your code with the below it should work.

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

const PrintHello = () => {
  return <Text> Hello Im working </Text>;
};
```